# OutOfMemory issue while running espresso tests in Android

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-espresso

I've been facing this issue (OutOfMemory) while running my espresso test suite on Kitkat and Lollipop devices. The suite runs perfectly fine on Marshmallow device. Below are more details and I would really appreciate if I could get any help in identifying the root cause of this issue. Below are more details :

1. OutofMemory occurs only when I run entire suite at once (175 tests) and the issue doesn't occur if I run each test set individually.
2. I tried to use System.gc() that is called after running every scenario, but still observed the OutOfmemory exception.
3. The exception occurs on different test script everytime I run and is not consistent on particular feature / test script.
4. The bitmaps used across the app are already compressed,so not sure if it has to do with the size of the images.
5. Below is the log of the recent run :

   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
   01-26 14:42:39.770 3476-4264/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 579 [01-26      14:42:39.778]
   01-26 14:42:42.470 3476-3476/? E/MotionRecognitionService: support TA ~
   01-26 14:42:45.180 4265-4317/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush      buffer to file cnt : 3 size : 0Kb duration : 39ms lastUpdatedAfter :   180367ms
   01-26 14:42:52.510 3476-3476/? E/MotionRecognitionService: support TA ~
   01-26 14:42:55.320 446-454/? E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by  finalizer
   01-26 14:42:56.900 446-454/? E/System: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:     OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack    trace available
   01-26 14:42:56.910 446-1088/? E/CrashReporting: ParseCrashReporting caught a OutOfMemoryError exception for com.capitalone.mobilebanking.dev.debug. Building report.
   01-26 14:42:56.910 446-18726/? E/CrashReporting: ParseCrashReporting caught a OutOfMemoryError exception for com.capitalone.mobilebanking.dev.debug. Building report.
   01-26 14:42:56.910 446-446/? E/MonitoringInstrumentation: Exception encountered by: Thread[main,5,main]. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
                                                         **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 40 byte allocation with 3960 free bytes and 3KB until OOM**
                                                             at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl(View.java:16723)
                                                             at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:16625)
                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17231)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3921)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                                                             at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl(View.java:16759)
                                                             at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:16625)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16445)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3905)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3885)
                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16424)
                                                             at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:325)
                                                             at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:331)
                                                             at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:366)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3134)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2933)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2522)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
   01-26 14:42:56.910 446-18726/? E/AndroidRuntime: **FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[AlertSubscriptionService]**
                                                Process: com.capitalone.mobilebanking.dev.debug, PID: 446
                                                **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:** OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
   01-26 14:42:56.910 446-1088/? E/CrashReporting: Handling exception for crash
                                               **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4092 byte allocation with 3928 free bytes and 3KB until OOM**
                                                   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
                                                   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
                                                   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
                                                   at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendTail(Matcher.java:285)
                                                   at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:321)
                                                   at gherkin.formatter.PrettyFormatter.indent(PrettyFormatter.java:469)
                                                   at gherkin.formatter.PrettyFormatter.printError(PrettyFormatter.java:385)
                                                   at gherkin.formatter.PrettyFormatter.printSteps(PrettyFormatter.java:133)
                                                   at gherkin.formatter.PrettyFormatter.replay(PrettyFormatter.java:121)
                                                   at gherkin.formatter.PrettyFormatter.eof(PrettyFormatter.java:421)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:34)
                                                   at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
                                                   at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:30)
                                                   at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:243)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
                                                   at $Proxy11.eof(Unknown Source)
                                                   at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
                                                   at cucumber.runtime.android.CucumberExecutor.execute(CucumberExecutor.java:113)
                                                   at cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentationCore.start(CucumberInstrumentationCore.java:88)
                                                   at com.capitalone.mobilebanking.espressoTests.Instrumentation.onStart(Instrumentation.java:133)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation

Comment: Have you taken heap dumps to look for leaks?  Particularly Activity leaks?

Comment: @GabeSechan : I am running QE espresso tests so not sure how to take heap dumps. Could you guide me here.

Comment: I got this during development _ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 0Kb duration_ suddenly. Re-install did work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue when I started running more than 300 Espresso tests at once.
Apparently, the memory is not cleared after each test which caused the OOM Error (OutOfMemoryError).

To fix the issue, I started using the [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator) which offers the following benefits for your testing environment:

- Minimal shared state. Each test runs in its own Instrumentation
  instance. Therefore, if your tests share app state, most of that
  shared state is removed from your device's CPU or memory after each
  test.
- **To remove all shared state from your device's CPU and memory after
  each test, use the clearPackageData flag.**
- Crashes are isolated. Even if one test crashes, it takes down only
  its own instance of Instrumentation, so the other tests in your suite
  still run.

I added the [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator) in my project build gradle file to fix the issue:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
   ...
   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   // The following argument makes the Android Test Orchestrator run its
   // "pm clear" command after each test invocation. This command ensures
   // that the app's state is completely cleared between tests.
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
 }

  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
}

dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
  androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: One should note that adding `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'` will also clear any code coverage data between tests. So if you want coverage reports from your espresso tests, orchestrator is useless apart from the fact that it can isolate failures and let the rest of the test suite run.